# How do you tell which tombstones are weaponized?

Tags: onrush

The *Blade* bike drops 'weaponized tombstones' which temporarily blind opponents who collect them.  As seen in video below.

Is there a way to see these coming before hitting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weaponized tombstones flash a bright whiter tone rapidly, you can actually see it in the video above once you know what you're looking for.